# How do I get Google Realtime to move the revision number up

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'm playing with the Google realtime API, specifically the [Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_sample).

I have a string at the root named *'text'* and I have it bound to the DOM element in the example.

No matter how much typing I do, I can't seem to figure out a way to get it to actually save to google Drive.  The file is there, but when I do a realtime/get API call for the file, I just get this:

API Endpoint: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/realtime`

```
{
 "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "revision": 1,
 "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the GET call with the same app credentials as you use to do the writing.  The realtime document is scoped to a particular app.

Comment: I'm using the realtime javascript library to do the writing... I'm confused as to why the Web API can't retrieve the contents of these files.  Am I not even actually writing to the file in the first place with the javascript library?

Comment: You are writing to the realtime document (which is different from the file contents) but if you are using realtime.get above with the same app id you should see contents.  How are you using the web API?

Comment: Right now, I'm just testing it out through the api docs... authing with my account and making the request passing the file_id of the realtime document.

Comment: This is where I'm making the realtime/get call...
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get

Comment: Right, so when you use the api test tool you are using a different app to make the request.  You need to make the request using the same app as you are writing with.

Comment: face*palm.  I see what you're saying now.  I'm going to try that out then.